# pycharm Community edition

Tags: django, templates, django-templates, pycharm

PyCharm Community edition

I want to use Python coding in HTML file. {% for album in all_album %} it treated as normally only. I want it to treat as python code.

[image: if and for is not treated as Python code]

Comment: Can share the template file?

Comment: in community edition template engine is not supported for django

Answer (score 1):

Since it is the community edition which is free, it doesn't support the django templating ways. You'll need to buy the **full version** if you want django templating in pycharm. You'll also notice the same kind of problem when you write javascript in your html template.

Comment: Actually, I resolved this problem. We can set the jinja2 in our settings.py..
visit this you would understand http://jonathanchu.is/posts/upgrading-jinja2-templates-django-18-with-admin/